# Question regarding the domain of an inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question

My calculus professor mentioned the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is a strictly increasing, then $\operatorname{Dom}f^{-1}=[f(a),f(b)]$. If $f$ is a strictly decreasing, then $\operatorname{Dom}f^{-1}=[f(b),f(a)]$.

After mentioning it, he proceed to say that the case where $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $(a,b)$ is more difficult to analyze. But that's all he said. So I'm wondering, what can we say about the domain of $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $(a,b)$? Is there any property that the domain of $f^{-1}$ holds whenever $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $(a,b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $(a,b)$, then $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and  $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exist (possibly $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively), and
$$\operatorname{Dom} f^{-1}=\bigl(\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x),\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)\bigr).$$

Answer (score 1):

Not much can be said about $\text{dom}(f^{-1})$ when the domain of $f$ is an open interval. This is because the image of $f$ under such circumstances can become unbounded, as is the case with $f(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)$. The domain of $f$ in this case is $(-1,1)$, but the image is $(-\infty,\infty)$.